# Should I play Ys VIII: Lacrimosa of Dana without playing previous games?

Tags: ys-series, ys-8-lacrimosa-of-dana

I was going to download Ys VIII Lacrimosa of Dana, but before doing so I realized it's the eighth game in the series. Should I play it without playing previous games?

Comment: I think it's probably safe to play it without playing the previous games in the series. (consider especially that Ys V has never been released in the west, though an English translation patch does exist). I would still recommend playing the previous games; they're good games! But you should be okay with just playing the one.